# how to access rows in csv file

Tags: python, csv

im trying to get the value of the first and the thirs row in a csv file.
my approach gives me the first and the 3rd character of the first row. instead of the fields in row 1 and 3. Would be great if someone could give me a tipp what im doing wrong!

```
lang_tags = []
tweets = []
#open and read csv file
with open("tweet-corpus.csv", "r") as csv_file:
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
for row in csv_file:
    lang_tags = row[0]
    tweets = row[2]
    for lan in lang_tags:
        print("lang: ", lang_tags)
        print("tweet: ", tweets)
```

Comment: if something can be solved with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/),it will be eventually solved with pandas. read about [csv_files](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Are you talking about the column or the row, assuming the former ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `csv reader` object.

**Ex:**

```
with open("tweet-corpus.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        lang_tags = row[0]
```

or

```
with open("tweet-corpus.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        lang_tags = row['YOURCOL_NAME']
        tweets = row['YOURCOL_NAME']
```

Comment: using reader obj and row[keyname] instead of row[0] worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If your data looks anything remotely like:

`col_name0, col_name1, col_name2, ...
value0, value1, value2, ...
value0, value1, value2, ...`

I recommend using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd # by convention, we always import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
column = df[column_name]
```